# How to decompress gzip or deflate in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, gzip, compression

I am trying to do this because http gzip decompression is not supported with client stack.

I see that GZipStream class is not available in Silverlight. Any way to still use it?

DotNetZip library is not for Sliverlight it seems.

SharpZipLib has GNU license which is a no go.

Any chance Silverlight 5 will add support for compression?

Any way of doing this other than writing gzip decompression from scratch ?

NEW:

**UPDATE: It seems that as of July 30, 2011 DotNetZip will support Silverlight!**

Comment: Yep. DotNetZip supperts silverlight now. 
It's free and very easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

SharpZipLib, although GPL, has a special exception which allows it to be used for commercial applications:

From http://sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/:

> The library is released under the GPL with the following exception:
>
> Linking this library statically or dynamically with other modules is making a combined work based on this library. Thus, the terms and conditions of the GNU General Public License cover the whole combination.
>
> As a special exception, the copyright holders of this library give you permission to link this library with independent modules to produce an executable, regardless of the license terms of these independent modules, and to copy and distribute the resulting executable under terms of your choice, provided that you also meet, for each linked independent module, the terms and conditions of the license of that module. An independent module is a module which is not derived from or based on this library. If you modify this library, you may extend this exception to your version of the library, but you are not obligated to do so. If you do not wish to do so, delete this exception statement from your version.

Comment: hey thanks for the tip. I did see that but the license exception is sketchy at best. What if the result is not an executable but a Silverlight xap file ? It annoys me that they chose GNU license and then made an exception not to make it GNU.

Comment: Although the license exception may be sketchy, there is a clarification which follows what I quoted above: "Bottom line In plain English this means you can use this library in commercial closed-source applications"

Answer (score 0):

If commercial components are on the menu, try WCF-Xtensions. It provides support for deflate, gzip, zlib, lzf3, lzf, bzip2 and lzma compression both for requests and responses. Should be able to do what you ask for.